# How to give a ''secret agent'' feel to a game?

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, fate, gm-preparation, spycraft

I am planning a one on one Fate game and I want it to feel and play like a secret agent story (think James Bond, Bourne, Taken, etc. maybe even a hint of heist movies as well, aka Ocean's eleven)

My plan is to flesh out an overarching conspiracy: it's goals, members, actions, impacts, etc. that operates in the world on its own.
Then, in the first game, I would have the player clash with said conspiracy, maybe they got caught in the crossfire, stumbled upon evidence of shady deals or got hired for a small job that backfired.

I am thinking of focusing on investigation and social encounters more than combat as I feel it fits the genre more.

**How would you make an game inspired by spy movies? What would be considered the key elements?**

Comment: I'm confused by this question. James Bond and Bourne films are quite different in tone and ethos, and I'm not sure why you have [system-agnostic], [fate], *and* [spycraft] system tags here. Additionally, it'd be great if you told us what research you've done on [spy games using Fate](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?filters=340_0_44284_0_0) and rejected or appreciated, so we don't repeat useless information and can be more confident our answers are useful to your goals (speculation and brainstorming doesn't work well on this site; it's a place for answers to specific problems).

Comment: It's worth asking *which* Bond movies you had in mind, too - their feel has changed *immensely* over the course of the series  (and feel is what you're asking about).

Comment: Wanting to run a spy-themed game that feels like a spy movie is a noble goal. Unfortunately, without knowing what "spy movie" means to you, we really can't answer it without writing a small book on the subject, and that makes this question Too Broad by the standards of this site.

Comment: There is a huge difference between different movies in the "spy" genre.  Are you talking about Bond, Bourne, or something like Russia House or Tinker, Tailor, Soldier, Spy?  I know that in the 80's, we played a TSR game called Top Secret.  You may want to look for that as a start.